# Current sensing on solenoid

Tags: mosfet, inductor, current-measurement

So I have the below circuit simulation on LTSpice and trying to understand why whenever I set V3 Low or Hi I always get current through L1. M2 acts as an enable switch, so what I was expecting is that when V3 was high no current would flow, but that's not the case.

[image: Driving Inductive Load]

Comment: Rather than analyze something that does work, use logic to drive only 1 switch and define all in/out specs. Yet I agree that should not conduct if Vgs is 0V to  +12v for PFET

Answer (score 3):

Sure. You are misusing M2. As a p-type it has a body diode with the anode at the source and cathode at the drain. So, whenever M1 is conducting, the body diode is forward biased, and current flows.

To do what you want, move M2 to the other side of the solenoid and reverse its orientation. That is, connect the source to your +12, and the drain to the solenoid.

Comment: Ok body diode makes sense, also I though a little more about this but when M4 is conducting it also puts the source of M2 at logic 0, so regardless of the gate drive on M2 it will always be conducting unless I bring the gate below logic 0. Maybe this is the other part of the issue. What if I just mirror M2 in place as is and connect source to L1?

Comment: @j.valerio - Nope. Think about what will happen to the gate voltage when both FETs are supposed to be on. Since M2 needs (let's say) 10 volts to turn on hard, this means that the solenoid will only see about 2 volts. Do as I say, and put M2 on the + side of the solenoid.